# Big Query Query the Table and Store Result

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to query on of the big query datasets and store the result in on of the table so my code :

```
    BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
     TableId destinationTable = TableId.of(datasetName, TableName);
    
    
 QueryJobConfiguration queryConfig = QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(my_query)
                    .setDestinationTable(destinationTable).setWriteDisposition(JobInfo.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND).
                            build();
            TableResult results = bigquery.query(queryConfig);
```

It's working fine but the problem is with the results it's giving me all the rows present in the `TableName` , result should only give me the result of my current query not all the rows present in the table. How to make sure results give me only current query result ?

Comment: Check this out - https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/usage/queries.html

Comment: It doesn't say my use case

Comment: The `results` should have only the rows returned by the query inside `my_query`. If it's returning all rows, there is something with the query. Please add more information on the snippet about your query and the code before so we can have an [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)